# upgrade to 12.04, mysqld up but can't log on

Tags: mysql

Sorry if this is the wrong place to post. I upgraded to 12.04 and mysql stopped working. I re-installed mysql server package. When  I try to log on to database I get:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
```

That file (mysqld.sock) doest not exist. Yet mysqld process is up and running. I see it when I go ps -ef.

Shutdown and restart mysql works fine, I just can't log on.
I have my database on a directory that is not the default installation data directory. I added my path to the apparmor configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

reset MySQL password .  you lose nothing . I am sure .

```
 http://ubuntu.flowconsult.at/en/mysql-set-change-reset-root-password
```

that URL can help you .

Comment: Sorry, I tried that, didn't work. When I do step 3 to change the password I get the same error.

 
$ mysql -u root mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
$

Comment: I also tried reconfiguring with: sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5
I got an error: Unable to set password for the MySQL "root" user.